# Internet Explorer resizing content after clicking/focusing on it

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox

I've tried searching for this but found nothing. Might be using the wrong keywords. I made a gfycat of the problem.

https://gfycat.com/BrownHighErin

I have content, I click on it in IE, and things resize. Everything is flexbox display model, there are no anchor or button tags, it's just an image on the left and a table on the right wrapped in some divs. The project has a massive number of pages all using flexbox. This is the first I've seen this happen. I have been able to fix it with pointer-events: none but I'd rather not use that solution.

Another thing, the IE inspector does not show a change in the width of the element when this happens. It always shows the pixel width that the image should be, but not what is displaying.

Works in Edge, Chrome & Firefox

Comment: Please post the relevant code here. Also, it looks like your description is missing some words in the second paragraph.

Comment: Have you tested it in other browsers and it works fine?  If so, which ones?

Comment: I unfortunately don't think I can post code as this project is not public yet. And my missing words were in html brackets, I guess they got removed. I was hoping this might just be some issue with IE that's known, and I'm just searching for the answer with the wrong keywords.

Comment: For posting HTML, you can use backticks (`) to enclose it, so it shows up as code.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, it's impossible to say for sure what the issue is. If it's only happening in IE, it's likely a compatibility issue. IE only has partial support for flexbox, as shown on [CanIUse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

**Some of the know issues with IE and flexbox include:**

- IE 11 requires a `flex-basis` property to be added
- IE10 and IE11 containers may calculate any flexed childrens' sizes correctly if the container has a `min-height` but no `height` property set, and if the container uses `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column`
- IE10 defaults `flex` to `0 0 auto`, not `0 1 auto`

See the [CanIUse flexbox page](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) for more details.